# images are saved upside down from front facing android camera

Tags: android, camera

i'm trying to capture an image from my front camera and save it into my gallery, it works fine with back camera in both orientations PORTRAIT and LANDSCAPE
but with the front camera it works fine with the Landscape only ,

> if it's PORTRAIT the image is rotated 180 degrees upside down
>   i have tried the following code as it 's the most common solution but nothing works

```
FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    fos.write(data);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0,
                            bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, false);
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    fos.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }``
```

Comment: `but nothing works`. Please explain better what happens. `fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);`. At this moment that file is deleted and set to size 0.  `fos.write(data);` What is happening here? `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);`. You load that empty file here. Better: put `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName); as first statement.
`

Comment: I see now that maybe you first try to save the bitmap in data to file and then loading the file as bitmap, rotate it and save it again. Well that approch can only work if you put a fos.close(); before using decodeFile().. And then after rotation you should create a new FileOutputStream. But why not rotate the bitmap before saving?

Answer (score 0):

Call this whenever you switch camera with new CameraId

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```